# Mistake in SageMathCell code, finding integral points on elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, elliptic-curves, sage

I've the following number:

$$12\left(n-2\right)^2x^3+36\left(n-2\right)x^2-12\left(n-5\right)\left(n-2\right)x+9\left(n-4\right)^2\tag1$$

Now I know that $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ and $n\ge3$ (and $n$ has a given value) besides that $x\in\mathbb{N}^+$ and $x\ge2$.

I want to check if the number is a perfect square, so I can rewrite $(1)$ as follows:

$$y^2=12\left(n-2\right)^2x^3+36\left(n-2\right)x^2-12\left(n-5\right)\left(n-2\right)x+9\left(n-4\right)^2\tag2$$

Where $y\in\mathbb{Z}$.

In this problem I've: $n=71$, the number is equal to;

$$y^2=57132x^3+2484x^2-54648x+40401\tag3$$

So, I used [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) to look for the integral points on the elliptic curve and the code that was used is the following:

```
E = EllipticCurve([0, β, 0, γ, δ])
P = E.integral_points()
for p in P:
    if p[0] % α == 0:
        print(p[0] // α, p[1] // α)
```

I found the coeficients I need to use using equation $(2)$ and $(3)$ (but I do not know if they are corect):

- $$\alpha=12(71-2)^2=57132\tag4$$
- $$\beta=36(71-2)=2484\tag5$$
- $$\gamma=-144(71-5)(71-2)^3=-3122149536\tag6$$
- $$\delta=1296(71-4)^2(71-2)^4=131871507195024\tag7$$

So the final code looks like:

```
E = EllipticCurve([0, 2484, 0, -3122149536, 131871507195024])
P = E.integral_points()
for p in P:
    if p[0] % 57132 == 0:
        print(p[0] // 57132, p[1] // 57132)
```

But I found no solutions and it should give at least one solution at $x=1585$.

> What mistake have I made?

Comment: Use EllipticCurve_from_cubic(y^2*z - (57132*x^3+2484*x^2*z-54648*x*z^2+40401*z^3)) to get a map from your cubic to a Weierstrass model without having to think. The forum for asking questions of this type is ask.sagemath.org.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich I've no idea what you mean by that comment, I'm sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter too early and now I have edited the comment.

Comment: I'm guessing that the SageMathCell computation timed out. I'm running SageMath on my desktop computer, and after running `E = EllipticCurve([0, 2484, 0, -3122149536, 131871507195024])`, the command `P = E.integral_points()` hasn't finished after more than an hour.

Comment: Voted to closed as this really belongs to another forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After about an hour and a half running SageMath 9.0.beta7 on my computer, I see this:

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve([0, 2484, 0, -3122149536, 131871507195024])
sage: P = E.integral_points()
sage: for p in P:
....:    if p[0] % 57132 == 0:
....:        print(p[0] // 57132, p[1] // 57132)
....:
(-1, 201)
(0, 201)
(1, 213)
(1585, 15083061)
```

Comment: Just being curious: what is the rank of that curve? Usually the computation of the Mordell-Weil group is the main task in `integral_points`, but situation might be different here, since the curve has such a large height. BTW this code looks very familiar to me: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459005/when-is-the-number-81-60-x-1-x-2-5-x-a-perfect-square-for-x-ge2-a/3459020#3459020

Comment: If you insert after the first line the command E.simon_two_descent(), then the whole thing only takes some minutes. The reason is that this line sets E.gens() faster than mwrank does. simon_two_descent even allows to give known points which could speed up a little bit further. - Moreover, since 57132 is divisible by 6 one can even switch to the global minimal model to recover all four points and that is done in seconds !

Comment: @WhatsUp: `E.rank()` returns 4.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich: confirmed: `E.simon_two_descent()` takes 6.5 seconds, after which `P = E.integral_points()` takes under a second (as opposed to 80-90 minutes before).

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Quite interesting! But I don't understand the logic here. In the documentation https://www.math.sciences.univ-nantes.fr/~sorger/chow/html/en/reference/plane_curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_number_field.html#sage.schemes.elliptic_curves.ell_number_field.EllipticCurve_number_field.simon_two_descent , it is mentioned *This method is used internally by the rank(), rank_bounds() and gens() methods*. But we don't supply any input here, so why does a mere default call to `simon_two_descent` (which is supposed to be used in e.g. `rank()`) speed up the computation?

Comment: Our curve is over $\mathbb{Q}$ and so rank() first uses mwrank. Over number field mwrank can't be used so simon's 2-descent is the default.